# didEnterRegion and didExitRegion animation conflicting

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, geofencing, clregion

I'm building an app that uses GeoFencing. My didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods are called as they're supposed to, seemingly in the correct order, but fails to update the UI accordingly.

**What works:**

- User enters region
- didEnterRegion gets called
- UI is updated correctly within that method

**What doesn't work:**

- User enter region
- User goes straight from one region to another
- didExitRegion is called
- UI updates
- didEnterRegion is called
- NSLogs indicate that everything executes in the correct order
- UI isn't updated. The UI updates that were done in didExitRegion remains.

My methods:

**Custom function to update label (called from didEnterRegion and didExitRegion):**

```
-(void)updateCurrentLocationLabelAndImage:(NSString *)locationText subLocationText:(NSString *)subLocationText;
{
// Clear existing animations before we begin
[self.locationLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.subLocationLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.ovalImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
if (![locationText isEqual:@""])
{
    // Only animate if the text changes
    if (![self.locationLabel.text isEqualToString:locationText])
    {
        // Update the ovalImageView
        CGSize maxLabelSize = CGSizeMake(([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.0267) * 2)), 64); // maximum label size
        float expectedLabelWidth = [locationText boundingRectWithSize:maxLabelSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:self.locationLabel.font } context:nil].size.width; // get expected width

        CGFloat xValueForImage = ((([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - expectedLabelWidth) / 2) - 25); // Calcuate the x-coordinate for the ovalImageView
        if (xValueForImage < 15)
        {
            xValueForImage = 15; // we don't want it to display off-screen
        }
        self.ovalImageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = xValueForImage;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self changeLabelText:self.subLocationLabel string:subLocationText];
// Update the subLocationLabel
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
            // Animate
            self.locationLabel.alpha = 0;
            self.ovalImageView.alpha = 1;
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // update the UI
        }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Set the text
            self.locationLabel.text = locationText;
            self.locationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
                // Animate
                self.locationLabel.alpha = 1;
            }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                // Complete
            }];
        }];
    }
} else if ([locationText isEqual:@""])
{
    // Move it to the center
    self.ovalImageViewLeadingConstraint.constant = (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 2) - 9); // Default center calculation for this image
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self changeLabelText:self.subLocationLabel string:subLocationText]; // Update the subLocationLabel
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
        self.locationLabel.alpha = 0;
        self.ovalImageView.alpha = 1;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Complete
        self.locationLabel.text = @"";
    }];
}
}
```

**But the label stays the same, even though it logs the correct order of execution and everything looks fine. Any ideas? I'm really stuck..**

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the log "Entered work region ..." come from?

Comment: Your event of entering region 2 overrides the value immediately after exiting region 1. Try seeing values to two different label and check..

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR The test label I added now gets set correct

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR do you have any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: It's working as expected. What is the functionality you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR Setting the text on a different UILabel works, but my intention is to set the "main" label that I'm actually using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69767/discussion-between-naveen-prasad-r-and-erik).

Answer (score 0):

To explain in detail,

lets consider a scenario of user exiting region1 and straight entering region2.

Step 1:

So, the event exit is fired, the following lines are executed,

```
    NSLog(@"changing text from: %@, to: %@", label.text, string);
    // Only animate if the text changes
    if (![label.text isEqualToString:string])
```

At this If check, the label text is "inside region" (which is for region 1). Since the method is called from the exit method, the parameter `string` will have the value "Outside region". Both the values are not same and hence the control enters this region.

Step 2: 
At this point you started an animation of duration 0.15, however the value of the label is not changed until the animation is completed as the code is in the completion block.

```
   // Complete
    label.text = string;
```

Step 3: 
The did enter region 2 event is fired. The label text is not yet up to date, so it excites the below line

```
NSLog(@"changing text from: %@, to: %@", label.text, string);
```

However since the label text is "inside region" and string value is also "inside region", the control moves out of the if condition.

```
if (![label.text isEqualToString:string])
```

To verify:

1. Pass in a customized string value while calling change label text making the text specific viz., "inside region 1", "exiting region 1", "inside region 2" etc., This way the value will be different and would get updated.
2. Set the value of the label immediately before animation.
3. Assign the value to the atomic string property and check for the property Value.

for eg:

```
@property (atomic, strong) NSString * currentLabelText;



-(void)changeLabelText:(UILabel *)label string:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"changing text from: %@, to: %@", label.text, string);
    // Only animate if the text changes

    if (![self. currentLabelText  isEqualToString:string])
    {
        self. currentLabelText = string; //Ultimately this would be our value
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{

        // Animate
        label.alpha = 0;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       // Complete
    label.text = self. currentLabelText;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations:^{
        // Animate
        label.alpha = 1;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Complete
    }];
}];
}
}
```

Or another way as it suites your requirement.

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite understand how to implement in my code. The label may contain another string than "Inside region something", etc. I need to somehow detect if an animation is currently running for a given label and if so, override it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this…

```
            static NSString *currentText;
            currentText = locationText;

            [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations: ^{
                // Animate
                self.locationLabel.alpha = 0;
                self.ovalImageView.alpha = 1;
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // update the UI
            } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                // Set the text

                if (![currentText isEqualToString:locationText]) {
                    return;
                }

                self.locationLabel.text = locationText;
                self.locationLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                [UIView animateWithDuration:.15 animations: ^{
                    // Animate
                    self.locationLabel.alpha = 1;
                } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                    // Complete
                }];
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to put your UI update code in a dispatch block to make sure the UI-Update will performed on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //... UI Update Code
});
```

I guess the main thread thing is your biggest problem. To me the code looks a bit strange at this points:

- you are mixing different data types (float, CGFloat, int)

refer to [CocoaTouch64BitGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW14) this could be a problem but I think it doesn't solve your layout issue. More critical are the magic numbers in general.

- your autolayout code could be a problem

I believe it isn't necessary to move ovalImageView by manipulating the LeadingConstraint. Just set the *contentMode* to center/left/right and autolayout will do the reset. If you realy need to change the constraint then do it in *[yourView updateConstraints]* method. If you want the labels width ask for it: *[label intrinsicContentsize]* and use *setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth* if you need it. If your autolayout code is correct no view will appear "off-screen".

- your animations could be a little bit jumpy

You use removeAllAnimations at first. Basically right but if you expect high frequented updates I'd recommend just to change the labels/images content while a previous animation runs. Otherwise your image jumps back and a new animation will start.

Comment: I'll try this but why is it better to make sure it's performed on the main thread?

Comment: I believe you're misunderstanding the problem. The animation works 100% flawless when I enter a region, go outside a region, then into a region - but if I jump straight from one region to another without going to an empty area first, then it calls the method which performs the animations twice, and the text displayed in the UILabel is therefore wrong. But all the controls stay in the correct place all the time